# How to convert from string to numeric value in R

Tags: string, r, graph, ggplot2, numeric

i'm looking to graph the heights of a group of people in R

B/c a height like 5-11 comes in as a string, I was wondering if there were any tips on how to convert to a number so it could be graphed.

Comment: 'require(stringr)' 'Split <- str_split(x, "-")' 'sapply(Split, function(x) x[1] + (x[2] / 11))'

Comment: @HuubHoofs Your solution seems to work if you add as.numeric in your function and /12 : sapply(Split, function(x) as.numeric(x[1]) + (as.numeric(x[2]) / 12)). Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It also works with base R functions:

```
sapply(strsplit(x, "-"), function(x) {x <- as.numeric(x); x[1] + x[2] / 12})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your data is a factor.  If this is correct you can edit all the levels to numeric values then convert the factor to a numeric vector.

```
levels(data$heights)  #Levels of the factor
levels(data$heights)<-c(5*12+10,5*12+11,6*12,6*12+1) #Renaming factors in numerical make sure
##the numbers are in the same order as in your levels
data$heights<-as.numeric(levels(data$heights))[data$heights]  #Changing factor GPA to numeric vector GPA
data$heights
```

Reminder that this works if your R read your data as a factor

Answer (score 0):

```
require(stringr) 
Split <- str_split(x, "-")
sapply(Split, function(x) x[1] + (x[2] / 11))
```